# SYNTAX to change the name of a salesperson only when their sales are <50

Tags: sql, syntax

I am looking for the syntax to change the name of salesperson Inga to Annette, but only where Inga's SALES are <50

I have attached a screenshot of the database - I have tried every syntax I can think of, I am positive it will be simple - I have just been stuck on this for a while.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UPDATE statement, like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET SalesPerson="Annette"
WHERE SalesPerson="Igna" AND SalesAmount>50;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked after disabling safe update options.